AttributeError: 'XLNetForQuestionAnsweringOutput' object has no attribute 'start_logits'
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset, random_split
from transformers import get_linear_schedule_with_warmup
import time
import datetime

# Chuyển mô hình sang chế độ đánh giá
model.eval()

# Theo dõi các biến để tính toán độ chính xác và loss
total_eval_accuracy = 0
total_eval_loss = 0
nb_eval_steps = 0

# Ghi lại thời gian bắt đầu
t0 = time.time()

# Không cần tính toán hoặc lưu gradient
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in test_dataloader:
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        b_input_ids, b_attention_mask, b_start_positions, b_end_positions, _ = batch

        outputs = model(b_input_ids, attention_mask=b_attention_mask, start_positions=b_start_positions, end_positions=b_end_positions)
        
        loss = outputs.loss
        total_eval_loss += loss.item()

        # Lấy logit dự đoán cho vị trí bắt đầu và kết thúc
        start_logits = outputs.start_logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        end_logits = outputs.end_logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        start_positions = b_start_positions.to('cpu').numpy()
        end_positions = b_end_positions.to('cpu').numpy()

        # Chuyển logit thành index dự đoán
        start_preds = np.argmax(start_logits, axis=-1)
        end_preds = np.argmax(end_logits, axis=-1)

        # Tính độ chính xác cho batch
        eval_accuracy = (np.sum(start_preds == start_positions) + np.sum(end_preds == end_positions)) / (len(start_preds) + len(end_preds))
        total_eval_accuracy += eval_accuracy

# Tính và in ra các thông số đánh giá
avg_loss = total_eval_loss / len(test_dataloader)
avg_accuracy = total_eval_accuracy / len(test_dataloader)
total_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)

print(f"Accuracy: {avg_accuracy:.2f}")
print(f"Average Test Loss: {avg_loss:.2f}")
print(f"Testing took: {total_time}")

`I have researched and tried to fix this bug. XLNetForQuestionAnsweringOutput cannot get access to start_logits and end_logits. I just saw some attributes like start_top_index and end_top_index. Are there any ways for me to get access to start_logits and end_logits.
I have imported xlnet from transformer`
Bug: Cell In[18], line 26
     23 total_eval_loss += loss.item()
     25 # Lấy logit dự đoán cho vị trí bắt đầu và kết thúc
---> 26 start_logits = outputs.start_logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
     27 end_logits = outputs.end_logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
     28 start_positions = b_start_positions.to('cpu').numpy()

AttributeError: 'XLNetForQuestionAnsweringOutput' object has no attribute 'start_logits'


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and error as text and not as an image.

i have edited already, thank you

XLNetForQuestionAnsweringSimple returns the logits you are looking for.
